# Group by en LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

estoy practicando con LINQ en c# y SQL SERVER y quería escribir esta consulta en LINQ:

```
SELECT Employees.FirstName, COUNT(Orders.OrderID) AS Orders
FROM  Employees INNER JOIN
Orders ON Employees.EmployeeID = Orders.EmployeeID
GROUP BY Employees.FirstName
```

Pero no soy capaz, ni en formato from ni con expresion lambda, ¿me podéis echar una mano porfavor ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te dejo la consulta y la doc de microsoft donde puedes buscar mas.

> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/group-query-results

```
var collection = from e in Employess
                 join o in Orders on e.EmployeeID equals o.EmployeeID
                 group e by e.FirstName into Empleados
                 select Empleados.
```